# loop keep printing trash values, handeling binary files

Tags: c, file, while-loop, binaryfiles

Im trying to figure out what cause this loop to handle my structs and then keep creating trash value, the inner loop is working and updating salaries and the outer loop I used before as a stand-alone(if I only use the print function who work with the same while loop without going thro this function it will print my 2 structs with no trash values) and it worked:

```
while (fread(&worker, sizeof(Employee), 1, file1) == 1)
    {
        fseek(file2, 0, SEEK_SET);
        while (fread(&salary, sizeof(SalaryIncrement), 1, file2) == 1)
        {
            if (worker.id == salary.idEmployee)
            {
                worker.salary += salary.Salaryincrement;
                fseek(file1, -ByteEmpolyee, SEEK_CUR);
                fwrite(&worker, ByteEmpolyee, 1, file1);
            }
        }

    }
```

im adding my full code as well if someone want to look at it, thanks in advance

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct
{
    long id;
    char name[20];
    float salary;
}Employee;

typedef struct
{
    long idEmployee;
    float Salaryincrement;
}SalaryIncrement;

void AddingEmployee(char* fileName);
void AddingSalaryIncrement(char* filename);
void UpdateSalary(char* filename, char* filename1);
void printEmployee(char* filename);

void main()
{
    AddingEmployee("ListEmployees.bin");
    AddingSalaryIncrement("SalaryIncrement.bin");
    UpdateSalary("ListEmployees.bin", "SalaryIncrement.bin");
    printEmployee("ListEmployees.bin");
    system("pause");
}

void AddingEmployee(char* filename)
{
    FILE* file1 = fopen(filename, "ab");
    if (file1 == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Employee worker;
    printf("Adding a new employee:\n");
    printf("\nPlease enter the employee's ID , name, Salary: ");
    scanf("%ld %s %f", &worker.id, worker.name, &worker.salary);
    fwrite(&worker, sizeof(Employee), 1, file1);
    fclose(file1);
}

void AddingSalaryIncrement(char* filename)
{
    FILE* file1 = fopen(filename, "ab");
    if (file1 == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    SalaryIncrement salary;
    printf("Add SlaryIncrement:\n");
    printf("Please inset the following: ID , salaryincrement: ");
    scanf("%ld %f", &salary.idEmployee, &salary.Salaryincrement);
    fwrite(&salary, sizeof(SalaryIncrement), 1, file1);
    fclose(file1);
}

void UpdateSalary(char* filename, char* filename1)
{
    Employee worker;
    SalaryIncrement salary;
    FILE* file1 = fopen(filename, "rb+");
    if (file1 == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE* file2 = fopen(filename1, "rb");
    if (file2 == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int ByteEmpolyee = sizeof(Employee);
    int ByteSalary = sizeof(SalaryIncrement);
    while (fread(&worker, sizeof(Employee), 1, file1) == 1)
    {
        fseek(file2, 0, SEEK_SET);
        while (fread(&salary, sizeof(SalaryIncrement), 1, file2) == 1)
        {
            if (worker.id == salary.idEmployee)
            {
                worker.salary += salary.Salaryincrement;
                fseek(file1, -ByteEmpolyee, SEEK_CUR);
                fwrite(&worker, ByteEmpolyee, 1, file1);
            }
        }

    }
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
}

void printEmployee(char* filename)
{
    Employee worker;
    FILE* file1 = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file1 == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fread(&worker, sizeof(Employee), 1, file1) == 1)
    {
        printf("ID: %ld\t\t Name: %s\t\t Salary: %0.2f\n", worker.id, worker.name, worker.salary);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this loop when I replaced it with this: (but it still happens with the other one and I still don't know why)

```
    fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(file1)/sizeof(Employee);
    fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        fread(&worker, sizeof(Employee), 1, file1);
        fseek(file2, 0, SEEK_SET);
        while (fread(&salary, sizeof(SalaryIncrement), 1, file2) == 1)
        {
            if (worker.id == salary.idEmployee)
            {
                worker.salary += salary.Salaryincrement;
                fseek(file1, -ByteEmpolyee, SEEK_CUR);
                fwrite(&worker, ByteEmpolyee, 1, file1);
            }
        }
    }
```